# Escalation in the context of multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, multiple-inheritance

In one of my exercises, I'm asked to use *escalation* to solve the problem. In the given resources, I can find very little about this, only that it's used in the context of multiple inheritance. Searches on Google and SO didn't help either. I think I understand how to solve the exercise, I just don't know which part of it is the *escalation* part.

If someone could provide me with a definition/example or resources to learn more about this I would be very thankful.

EDIT:
The term is used once in the course slides in the following context:

```
Multiple Inheritance 
...
 - if multiple classes must share a common base class
     -- a.k.a. escalation 
...
```

Comment: If this is a term that your teacher used I would start by asking them for clarification (I've never heard it before either)

Comment: I have 20+ years of OO programming, and this is an unfamiliar usage to me, too. Perhaps it is referring to [upcasting and downcasting](https://www.tutorialcup.com/cplusplus/upcasting-downcasting.htm) -- where you "escalate" by moving up the hierarchy (or down, depending on the orientation of your hierarchy)?

Comment: Thanks, I will next time I see him but I want to work on the exercise before that. Good to know though that it seems to be something course-specific.

Comment: Is it possible they said "encapsulation"?

Comment: @parktomatomi No, it's also mentioned a single time in the slides where it says: Multiple Inheritance [...] - if multiple classes must share a common base class -- aka **escalation** [...], with the given example I think that it means something like to factor a part that two classes have in common out (enum in the example), create it in a base class and let the two classes inherit it. But again, I'm not sure which is why I'm asking:)

Comment: Are you talking about [privilege escalation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5248594/10957435)?